# Embedded kafka throws exception when producing within multiple scalatest suits

Tags: apache-kafka, scalatest

Here is how my test suit is configured.

```
  "test payments" should {
    "Add 100 credits" in {
      runTeamTest { team =>
        withRunningKafka {
          val addCreditsRequest = AddCreditsRequest(team.id.stringify, member1Email, 100)
          TestCommon.makeRequestAndCheck(
            member1Email,
            TeamApiGenerated.addCredits().url,
            Helpers.POST,
            Json.toJson(addCreditsRequest),
            OK
          )

          val foundTeam = TestCommon.waitForFuture(TeamDao.findOneById(team.id))
          foundTeam.get.credits mustEqual initialCreditAmount + 100
        }
      }
    }

    "deduct 100 credits" in {
      runTeamTest { team =>
        withRunningKafka {
          val deductCreditsRequest = DeductCreditsRequest(team.id.stringify, member1Email, 100)
          TestCommon.makeRequestAndCheck(
            member1Email,
            TeamApiGenerated.deductCredits().url,
            Helpers.POST,
            Json.toJson(deductCreditsRequest),
            OK
          )

          val foundTeam = TestCommon.waitForFuture(TeamDao.findOneById(team.id))
          foundTeam.get.credits mustEqual initialCreditAmount - 100
        }
      }
    }
```

Within Scalatest, the overarching suit name is `"test payments"` and the subsequent tests inside it have issues after the first one is run. If I run each of the two tests individually, they will succeed, but if I run the entire suit, the first succeeds and the second returns a `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.` exception. The code above doesn't display the code within the controllers that are being tested, but within the controller, I have a kafka consumer that is constantly polling and `close()` isn't called on it within the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you use companion object methods `EmbeddedKafka.start()` and `EmbeddedKafka.stop()` in the `beforeAll` and `afterAll` sections. This way you also avoid stopping / starting Kafka again for a single test class.

Also try to make sure you're not trying to start 2 or more instances of Kafka on the same port at the same time.

Comment: Is there a way to check if a Kafka cluster which was passed a stop command has actually died or not. @manub

Comment: You could try checking if there's a TCP server listening on the Kafka port. If you check the tests in the source that's how the server going down is verified

Comment: Hi @manub, I know its been 3 years, but can you please comment [here]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389776/embedded-kafka-unable-to-retrieve-a-message-from-kafka-in-5000ms?rq=1) too? Thanks a million.

Comment: Actually, my spark app was storing checkpoints locally, and so reruns of the tests would not read the same incoming messages on EmbeddedKafka, hence error. So, I solved it by removing the checkpoints directory on every run of the test-suite. If you have a similar setup, removing checkpoints dir might help.