# Embedded Kafka: Unable to retrieve a message from Kafka in 5000ms

Tags: testing, apache-kafka

I'm using embedded Kafka to do some integration test. My code insert one element in Kafka and I check in my test that this record is right. 
I have many tests that have this behavior. If I execute a single test, it always work, but if I execute all the test, some of them could fail randomly.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Unable to retrieve a message from Kafka in 5000ms
```

My code:

```
    val recordFromKafka = DesMyClass.deserialize(EmbeddedKafka.consumeFirstMessageFrom(topic))
    assertResult(result) {
      recordFromKafka
    }
```

I get this error and the next test fails too because I recover the record from the last test,, producing a chain of errors.

It seems that it's a problem from Kafka. Any idea? I have thought to call again the operation consumeFirstMessageFrom if I don't get any record,, but it doesn't seem a good way to do it. I'm using the version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.manub</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest-embedded-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Are all the tests reading/writing to a single topic?

Comment: Yes, it's the same topic, but tests aren't executed in parallel.

Comment: Hey @manub, can you help here? I'm running into this same issue. I'm working with a Spark Application on maven. I could post my maven config here, if needed?